# Does the USCIS publish some statistics on the most common reasons for RFEs for Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization Form)?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

I wonder whether the USCIS publish some statistics on the most common reasons for RFEs for Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization Form).

As [mkennedy](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/2303/mkennedy) [mentioned](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24151/does-the-uscis-publish-some-statistics-on-the-most-common-reasons-for-rfes-for-f#comment39940_24151) in a comment, the USCIS publishes the list of the [top reasons for an RFE for H-1B in 2018](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/data/understanding-requests-for-evidence-h-1b-petitions-in-fiscal-year-2018.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/data/understanding-requests-for-evidence-h-1b-petitions-in-fiscal-year-2018.pdf)). I'm looking for a similar document for Form N-400.

Comment: here's a list of [top reasons from 2018](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/data/understanding-requests-for-evidence-h-1b-petitions-in-fiscal-year-2018.pdf) for H-1B, not green card though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the USCIS does not publish some statistics on the most common reasons for RFEs for Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization Form).

However, some trackers list RFEs that applicants received, so one could construct an empirical distribution from them. E.g., from https://www.immihelp.com/us-citizenship-tracker:

- Evidence of marital status
- Proof of child support payments
- Birth certificate translation
- Bring proof of payment for speed ticket to interview
- Tax documents, tax returns
- Children's birth certificate